# Insert data into HIVE over HADOOP

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am using **hadoop-1.0.4 and hive-0.10.0 in redhat5**. Service start successfully. I am able to create, drop, select table easily but I don't know how to insert data.

For example I have two text box and on button click I want to store data in table (userInfo). I have no clue how to store textbox vaue in userInfo(id,password).

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";


try {
          Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/enggheads","", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
        stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
        // show tables
        String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }
```

It's Java, but I don't know how to insert two field value because Hive insertion is different than MySQL or other database syntax.

Comment: I think you can use JDBC driver to connect to hive db and can insert values of your frontend

Comment: yse I am using JDBC Driver and also try to insert through frontend. but i don't find insertion query for insert two fields. I am also edit my ques and paste code.

Comment: insert into table tblname(columnlist) select columnlist from dual may work.where dual is one row,one column dummy table

Comment: Thanx balaswamy but i have no one dummy table.After searching i find insertion in hive only done through (txt ar csv file) ar through another table. its necessary to create dummy table for insertion?

Comment: to insert data into table we load it from file or from select query,here we dont have file ,so selecting the data from dummy table.so it it will be like insert into table userinfo select idvalue,pwdvalue from dual.for this reason you should have a dummy table in hive database .

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-dml.html#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Comment: ok so first i'll create table and dummy table(dual) than insert data into main table using select value from dual. plz tell me am i right ar wrong bcoz i also go through this link but little bit confusing for me in insertion command.

Comment: create a file with data x and a table with single column as string pointing to that file,then use insert into table tblname select 1,2 from dual,here 1,2 will be inserted into table tblname say 1,2 are taken from front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dummy table in hive like below

```
create table dummy(dummy string) location '/path';
```

Above path will have a file which contains data `X`

Now run insert query from jdbc driver like below.

```
insert into table tblname select forntendvalue1,frontendvalue2 from dual;
```

Comment: Thankyou its working but i want to know these dummy tables exist in path ar not? Because I am not able to see this table on given path.

Comment: one more question if i am adding data in different tables than also create a one new dummy table? thes dummy tables occupy space ar not?

Comment: one dummy table can be used for all,these do not occupy much space ,check space with hadoop fs -dus /path command

Comment: Can you please give me a link where I get the full information about dummy table insertion in hive??

Comment: I dont have any link regarding this is my original idea on your problem

Comment: ok. I have a problem in database one entry repeated 32 times. Example :1) create a dummy table 2) create a main table 3) when insert in main table and check in warehouse/dbname/table 4) one entry repeated in 32 times . Please suggest if u know..

Comment: because u might be having 32 rows in dummy table,dummy table should have one row and one column only

Comment: I am using syntax for create dummy table - create table dummy (id int , name string) location '/path' ; so how to know total rows and columns in dummy table?

Comment: I am also using partitions in main table . Example create table tablename(id int, name string) partitioned (name string);

Comment: partition column should not be part of main columns like name two times not allowed post another query if have issues

Comment: yes i know partition column not the part of main column. But you have any idea how to remove insertion problem(32 rows inserted in one time)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31558/discussion-between-balaswamy-vaddeman-and-ruchi)